# Pentaho Report for Mongodb Date parameter default value

Tags: mongodb, pentaho

The query is:

```
{{"$match": todaysdate : {$gte: {$date:"${datevalue}"}},
{_id:"field1"}}
```

where parameter datevalue is of type string.

Can we use the function formula as

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(TODAY()); "YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
```

Need to give default value to the parameter "datevalue". Or is there anyother way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee that the value you pass into the MongoDB datasource is valid, I would create a formula-expression or hidden-parameter with a post-processing formula to compute a derived value that is:

- if "datevalue" is not empty: datevalue
- if "datevalue" is empty: today formatted as time string.

and the formula for that is:

```
=IF(ISEMPTY([datevalue]); MESSAGE("{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ}"; TODAY()); [datevalue])
```